# itemize/enumerate are throwing a TeX-deactivate-mark issue in Aquamacs

Tags: itemize, auctex, aquamacs

I am using Aquamacs 3.4 in macOS 10.14.3, and have been using Aquamacs for years. When I insert an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment into a LaTeX document using <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>, I get the expected prompt:

> (Optional) Options (k=v):

If I press <kbd>RET</kbd>, then the environment appears in my document. Until today, this would also insert the first `\item`. Since today (without having updated Aquamacs, macOS, or my LaTeX distribution), I instead get the mystifying status message:

> Symbol's function definition is void: TeX-deactivate-mark

What does this message mean? What is going wrong, and how do I fix it and get my `\item` back? I've tried searching online, but haven't found anything useful regarding `TeX-deactivate-mark`. <kbd>C-h v</kbd> and <kbd>C-h f</kbd> in Aquamacs don't seem to know about `TeX-deactivate-mark` either. I'm not sure whether this is an issue with Aquamacs, AUCTeX, or my LaTeX distribution.

Curiously, <kbd>M-RET</kbd> within the environment DOES create an `\item` as expected.

Thanks for any help; this is my first Stack Exchange post.

UPDATE: In a comment below, @ArashEsbati has helped pin down the problem, and has addressed all of my questions except for "how do I fix it?". As suggested, I entered `M-x load-list-path-shadows`, which gave an output:

> /Users/[username]/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Packages/elpa/auctex-12.1.2/tex-site hides /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/tex-site

followed by 26 similar lines. Each line involves an item in `/Users/.../auctex-12.1.2` "hiding" a corresponding item in `/Applications/.../edit-modes`. It seems the items in `/Applications/.../edit-modes/` are out of date, and are the source of my problem. How do I resolve this conflict? (e.g. is it safe to delete the folder `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes`?)

Comment: This message means that your AUCTeX installation is looking for a function which was removed from AUCTeX in Dec. 2017.  I suspect you have multiple AUCTeX's installed on your system.  Open your .tex file and trigger the message, then do `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` and watch for any duplications.  Maybe that gives you an idea.

Comment: Thank you @ArashEsbati -- this did indeed isolate my problem. See my edits above. (I was not previously aware of `list-load-path-shadows`, and did not know that `TeX-deactivate-mark` was removed in 2017.)

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, @ArashEsbati speculated I had multiple AUCTeXs installed, and suggested trying `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` in Aquamacs after triggering the odd status message in a .tex file.

@ArashEsbati was correct: `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` revealed that I did indeed have two AUCTeXs installed. I removed one, then found that my .tex files failed to compile with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, but DID compile when Aquamacs was loaded without customizations. It seems I inadvertently ruined my `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/customizations.el` file last week; I think this was the ultimate source of my posted problem. At this point it was quicker (for me) to delete all TeX-mode customizations from `customizations.el`, to delete all AUCTeXs and reinstall Aquamacs, to delete all installed LaTeX distributions, and to download the most recent MacTeX. Works fine now.